optimize.newton error: Failed to converge after some iterations, value is using an equation that contains norm.cdf
I am using scipy from Python in order to solve an equation that contains norm.cdf.
I have an equation similar to this:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.misc import derivative
from scipy import optimize

a_=1
b_=1
x0=2
def f(x, a=a_, b=b_):
    return (a*x*norm.cdf(b/x))

root = optimize.newton(f, x0, args=(a_, b_))
print(f"The root of the equation is approximately {root}")

However I got as a result this error:
RuntimeError: Failed to converge after 50 iterations, value is -0.12105344527421698.

Someone can help me in order to get the result?

If norm.cdf(x) is what other packages call erfc(x) then I suggest you plot your function with those chosen parameters and take a look at it! It is everywhere positive. It is most nearly at a root when x = +machine_eps and as written will generate division by zero when x==0. For small negative values of x it has value ~2x. In double precision it evaluates to zero for 0<x<0.037 (approx).

@MartinBrown, the function is not positive everywhere, there is a x factor in addition of norm.cdf(1/x). The problem is not only the singularity at x=0 (which is also the root) but the whole shape of the function that makes Newton algorithm fails to find the root if the initial guess is not enough close to the solution. Nice example of challenging function for numerical solver.

@jlandercy it is a feature of NR that it can easily go AWOL if the initial guess is not within the convergence zone of a solution and that functions with very shallow gradients can be a problem for it. Halley's method is a bit better in that respect. I think your answer (now deleted was close enough to right that I would have upvoted it if it was still there). Numerically at double precision there is a root in the formula as written for the range I specified. I'm a bit surprised numpy didn't latch onto that.

@MartinBrown, I had a problem with my connection, the answer is now online again.

Exact solution
You are facing two challenges:

Singularity at x=0 (which is in addition the root of your function);
Slow convergence or impossible convergence of Newton method (because of the shape of the function);


Given the following model:
def model(x, a=1, b=1):
    return a * x * stats.norm.cdf(b / x)

We can solve this equation by hand using limits:
0 * cdf(1/0+) = 0 * cdf(inf) = 0 * 1 = 0
0 * cdf(1/0-) = 0 * cdf(-inf) = 0 * 0 = 0

Which confirms 0 is indeed a root of your function.
Numerical solution
This is a good function example to challenge numerical solvers.
Anyway, giving a initial guess is sufficient to find the desired root:
sol = optimize.newton(model, x0=0.1)  # 0.0

